# p:commandLink doesn't trigger p:blockUI

Tags: jsf, exception, primefaces, blockui

I am using PrimeFaces. Here is the code:

```
<h:form>    
    <p:dataTable...>
        <p:column...>
            <p:commandLink id="featuresLinkId"...>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<p:blockUI block=":smForm" trigger="featuresLinkId">
    <p:graphicImage alt="loader image" value="/images/loader.gif"/> 
</p:blockUI>
```

When the page is being loaded, I see the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
Cannot find component with identifier "featuresLinkId" in view.
```

Seems like `commandLink` can't be used to trigger `blockUI` in such a scenario. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it won't find that compnent because its inside the form/datatable.

Make changes as

1-

```
<h:form id="formId">
```

2-

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl">
```

3-

```
<p:blockUI block=":smForm" trigger=":formId:tbl:featuresLinkId">
```

Try above .

Comment: That's it, thanks! However, it still doesn't work, even the above exception is gone. Thanks again.

Comment: The reason is not working is zargarf answer. Its a bug in 3.5 (I have not tested).

Comment: Thanks. This bug isn't fixes since very long, now I remember having it in 3.4.1 too.

Comment: ^ I feel bad. Can you try suggested solution by zargarf.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug in Primefaces 3.5 I think
see: [How to reference p:commandLink in p:dataTable from p:blockUI trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893751/how-to-reference-pcommandlink-in-pdatatable-from-pblockui-trigger)

You could try using JQuery BlockUI http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/