# Primefaces 6.0 blockUI doesn't show for commandButton's in dataTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a `p:dataTable` which has a column which has `p:commandButtons` which performs a specific action against that row, that action goes off does a number of things and then navigates to a different page. As it takes a few seconds to do those things I'd like to make it obvious to the user that something is happening, so I'm attempting to use a `p:blockUI` like so

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:dataTable ...>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton onclick="bui.show()" oncomplete="bui.hide()" .../>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<p:blockUI widgetVar="bui" block="myForm"/>
```

The blockUI doesn't show however, is there something wrong with the approach above?

Comment: did you try to update it ?!?

Comment: update what? I based my code on this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/14894133/564045

Comment: to know if the problem is in the `onclick` or in the `oncomplete` try to remove the `oncomplete` and make an update about the `dataTable` do you understand what i mean ?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know you can't call for `blockUI` with a `widgetVar` like that.

The correct way is this: `PF('widgetVar').method;`.

In your case:  `PF('bui').show();` and `PF('bui').hide();`

You can read more here: [Intro To PrimeFaces widgetVar](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/).

Comment: Perfect thank you! The answer I was basing my code on was misleading, perhaps due to different versions of primefaces